# Test that a function calls another function in an ES6 module with Sinon.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, sinon

I want to test that a function in an ES6 module calls another function using Sinon.js. Here's the basic layout of what I'm doing:

foo.js

```
export function bar() {
 baz();
}

export function baz() {
 ...
}
```

test.js

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import * as Foo from '.../foo';

describe('bar', function() {
  it('should call baz', function() {
    let spy = sinon.spy(Foo, 'baz');
    spy.callCount.should.eql(0);

    Foo.bar();

    spy.calledOnce.should.eql(true);
  });
});
```

But the spy does not pick up the call to `baz()`. Is there some other way I can set up the module or the test to allow sinon to pick this up? My alternative is to make some basic assertion on something baz does, but I obviously don't want to be doing that.

From what I've seen online I'm wondering if this is even possible with the code laid out as-is or if I need to restructure it to get what I want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're right in thinking this isn't possible with the way the module is currently structured.

When the code is executed, the `baz` reference inside `function bar` is resolved against the local implementation. You can't modify that since outside of the module code there's no access to the internals.

You *do* have access to exported properties, but you can't mutate these and so you can't affect the module.

One way to change that is using code like this:

```
let obj = {};
obj.bar = function () {
 this.baz();
}

obj.baz = function() {
 ...
}

export default obj;
```

Now if you override `baz` in the imported object you *will* affect the internals of `bar`.

Having said that, that feels pretty clunky. Other methods of controlling behaviors exist such as dependency injection.

Also, you should consider whether or not you actually care if `baz` was called. In standard "black-box testing", you don't care *how* something is done, you only care what side effects it generated. For that, test if the side effects you expected happened and that nothing else was done.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I thought as much, and had a feeling I'd have to take a more black-box approach.