# stubbing a function in a proxyquired object

Tags: unit-testing, sinon, stubs, proxyquire

I want to unit-test the following simplified module:

```
const Logger = require('logplease');
const logger = Logger.create('utils');

const tester = {

    one: () => {
        logger.log('called real one()');
        tester.two();
    },
    two: () => {
        logger.log('called real two()');
    },
};

module.exports = {
    one: tester.one,
    two: tester.two
};
```

I'm replacing the external dependency `logplease` using [Proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire), which works very well. However I need to stub `two()` because I want to unit-test `one()` while eliminating the side-effects `two()` produces when it runs in real code.

```
it.only('stubbing functions on the "proxyquired" object under test', function(done) {

    const loggerStub = {
        create: () => {
            return { log: (msg) => { console.log('fake logger: ', msg); } };
        }
    };

    let tester = proxyquire('../tester', { 'logplease': loggerStub });

    let stub2 = sinon.stub(
        tester, 
        'two', 
        () => { 
            console.log('called fake stub of two()'); 
        }
    );

    tester.one();

    console.log('call count 2: ', stub2.callCount);
    done();
});
```

Output I get:

```
fake logger:  called real one() 
fake logger:  called real two() 
call count 2: 0
```

Output I expect:

```
fake logger:  called real one() 
called fake stub of two()
call count 2: 1
```

Why doesn't my stub function run?

Comment: I may have found my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111367/test-that-a-function-calls-another-function-in-an-es6-module-with-sinon-js

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

```
const Logger = require('logplease');
const logger = Logger.create('utils');

const tester = {

    one: () => {
        logger.log('called real one()');
        tester.two();
    },
    two: () => {
        logger.log('called real two()');
    },
};

module.exports = tester;
```

Explanation: **scope**

You exported one and two as:

```
module.exports = {
    one: tester.one,
    two: tester.two
};
```

In this case **tester.one** knows only about this function:

```
two: () => {
    logger.log('called real two()');
}
```

and have no idea about stubbed **two**. So you have two versions of **two**, *just try to invoke **tester.two()** inside test*.